# PHP if statement null

Tags: php

I have this `if` statement in my controller:

```
if($parent == $page->parent)
```

Where `$parent == null` sometimes, when `$parent` is for example `16` it executes my if statement but only when its null it doesn't execute it what am I doing wrong?

Here's my controller:

```
public function updateMenu($id)
{
    $page = Page::find($id);
    $parent = Input::get('parent');
    $new_order = Input::get('index');

        if($parent == $page->parent)
        {
            if($page->order_id > $new_order)
            {
                DB::table('pages')
                    ->where('parent',$parent)
                    ->where('order_id', '<', $page->order_id)
                    ->increment('order_id');
            }
            else
            {
                DB::table('pages')
                    ->where('parent',$parent)
                    ->where('order_id', '>=', $page->order_id)
                    ->decrement('order_id');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            DB::table('pages')
                ->where('parent',$page->parent)
                ->where('order_id', '>', $page->order_id)
                ->decrement('order_id');    
        }



    $page->order_id = Input::get('index');
    $page->parent = Input::get('parent');

    $page->save();

    return $id;
}
```

I'm making a sortable list, can anyone see a problem?

Comment: Check is `$parent` & `$page->parent` are coming null ?

Comment: If `$page->parent == 16` and `$parent == null` your `if` statement will compare: `null == 16` that's definitely `false`.

Comment: i'm passing the new parent with ajax so if the parent stays the same $parent = null and then checks in my database for it's current parent wich results in $page->parent = 0 but null == 0 doesn't execute, instead of $parent = 16 and current parent $page->parent = 16 , 16 = 16 it executes

Answer (score 0):

a statement like this `if($parent == $page->parent)` returns true or false. So if it´s value is `null` it goes to the `else` statement.